# Does HTML for Facebook instant articles API submission need to be html5 or same as rss format

Tags: facebook

Seems to be some degree of ambiguity in FB doco for this.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instant-articles/api (under Create new article)

Using the API they say you can submit the html of the page of interest implying full unadulterated site html5 html.

For RSS its a somewhat bespoke html format.

Can anyone confirm the API html needs to be the same as the RSS html.

Answer (score -1):

> Using the API they say you can submit the html of the page of interest

No, it doesn’t say that. It says,

> html_source [required] – Full HTML markup of article.

That article refers to an Instant Article here (and not just any kind of “article” with full-blown HTML you might have on your website) should be obvious.

> Can anyone confirm the API html needs to be the same as the RSS html.

Of course it expects the markup to consist only of what is allowed for Instant Articles. It is not a *magic converter* that you just drop your web pages into and it’ll do the rest for you.

Comment: Thanks for the snooty response so tedious on SO these days. "Full HTML markup of article" is ambigous and can easily be interpreted as the html you would consider your normal site would use. They could have said compatible html or pointed you to the their html guide but they didnt. The point of the post was to clarify the issue.